# Angular 5 - Populate form with mysql data

Tags: php, angular, typescript

i'm new with angular 5.
I'm trying to populate a form with data from a database.
So far this it hid my form and from the ts side it only shows null.

**PHP code:**

```
include ('conexion.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE id=".$id;

if($con){

if(!$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) die();

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$arreglo[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($arreglo);
}else{
die ("error");
}
```

**form.html:(the ngModel i used with or without brackets)**

```
<div class="forms">
  <form method="post"  *ngFor="let x of datos">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-10" (ngModel)="x.nombre" name="nombre" value="x.nombre" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Apellido Paterno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-10"  (ngModel)="x.a_paterno"  name="a_paterno"  value="x.a_paterno"  required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Apellido Materno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-10"   (ngModel)="x.a_materno"  name="a_materno" value="x.a_materno" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Edad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-10"    (ngModel)="x.edad" name="edad"  value="x.edad" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label>Carrera</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-10" (ngModel)="x.carrera"  name="carrera"  value="x.carrera" required />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <label>Direccion</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-12"  (ngModel)="x.direccion"  name="direccion"  value="x.direccion" required/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <br>
        <label>Telefono</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-12"  (ngModel)="x.telefono" name="telefono"  value="x.telefono" required/>
      </div>

    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Datos</button>
    <br>
    <br>
  </form>
</div>
```

**form.ts:**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.mostrarDatos();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
      console.log('Mi id' + this.id);
    });
  }
  mostrarDatos() {
    console.log(this.id);
   this.http.get('http://localhost/crudu/mostrarID.php?id=' + this.id).subscribe((data) => {
     this.datos = data;
     console.log(this.datos);

   });
  }
```

I've been trying with many solutions but nothing at the end.
Also in my route or url it shows as eUsuario/1

Comment: Do you want to prefill the form with some data that you fetched from the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `(ngModel)` with `[(ngModel)]`. Currently you have a binding from the input into model but not vice versa.

Remove the call of `mostrarDatos` from the constructor and call it after you get the `id`.

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    console.log('Mi id' + this.id);
    this.mostrarDatos();
});
```